# Unity MLAgents-learn doesn't seem to be training at all

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As the title mentions, I run mlagents-learn but the agent only does the same exact action. I am creating an AI that can drive a car through an easy straight course through reinforcement learning. I have added checkpoints throughout the road in order for the agent to receive positive feedback everytime it gets closer to the goal. However, the agent does not seem to be training at all and instead repeats the same exact action (ex. hitting the wall at the same exact angle). I do not have ray perception sensors due to how easy the course is. I mostly took the code from code monkey's ml agent's tutorial video, but unlike his video, my agent does not train at all.

Another thing: I have GetCumulativeReward() and I noticed that every time the agent ran into a wall (it's supposed to be -1f reward), the total reward doesn't seem to decrement. Perhaps the program is not picking up on the negative rewards?

- when I try to run mlagents-learn for a long time, it quits out after like a minute and prints "Aborted (core dumped).

  ```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using Unity.MLAgents;
    using Unity.MLAgents.Actuators;
    using Unity.MLAgents.Sensors;

    public class MoveAgent : Agent
    {
        [SerializeField] 
        private Transform targetTransform;

        public override void OnEpisodeBegin(){
            transform.position = new Vector3(5.27417f, 0, -80.1366f);
        }

        public override void CollectObservations(VectorSensor sensor){
            sensor.AddObservation(transform.position);
            sensor.AddObservation(targetTransform.position);
        }

        public override void OnActionReceived(ActionBuffers actions){
            float moveX = actions.ContinuousActions[0];
            float moveZ = actions.ContinuousActions[1];

            float moveSpeed = 10f;

            transform.position += new Vector3(moveX, 0, moveZ) * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;
        }

        public override void Heuristic(in ActionBuffers actionsOut){
            ActionSegment<float> continuousActions = actionsOut.ContinuousActions;
            continuousActions[0] = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
            continuousActions[1] = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        }

        private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){
            if (other.TryGetComponent<Goal>(out Goal goal)){
                AddReward(+1f);
                EndEpisode();
            }

            if (other.TryGetComponent<Wall>(out Wall wall)){
                AddReward(-1f);
                EndEpisode();
            }

            if(other.TryGetComponent<Car>(out Car car)){
                AddReward(-1f);
                EndEpisode();
            }

            if(other.TryGetComponent<Checkpoint>(out Checkpoint checkpoint)){
                AddReward(+1f);
            }
            Debug.Log("Reward:" );
            Debug.Log(GetCumulativeReward());
        }
  ```

  }

Comment: Have you tried bigger rewards?

Comment: Yes I tried changing the rewards to +10f, -10f, -5f, -5f, and +5f :(